# How does jQuery work : I get "Cannot set property xxx of undefined" when trying a similar prototype thing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

How does JQuery handle the "Cannot set property xxx of undefined" issue?" If I have:

```
function Foo() {
   Foo.fn = Foo.prototype;
}
```

Then I have an extension JavaScript file with this code:

```
(function(foo) {
   foo.fn.myPlugin = function() {
       //return something here
   };
})(Foo);
```

I get an error that says "Cannot set property myPlugin of undefined." Funny enough if I just copy the plugin code into FireBug or Chrome and execute it in the console, it works fine and attaches and works as expected like:

```
foo.myPlugin();
```

I'm guessing my problem either comes from the timing of the browser loading the document, or the fact that my existing object isn't inside of it's own namespace. I'm wondering if this only works when you define a class using the var syntax??

I don't know...from what I understand...either should work.

Comment: If you're asking why your code doesn't work, you might want to change the title.  jQuery doesn't have a "Cannot set property xxx of undefined" issue, at least not as far as I know.

Comment: I'm actually asking how jQuery works...maybe my title is confusing I'll see if I can change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Baz() {
   return this;
}
Baz.prototype.fn = Baz.prototype;
var Foo = new Baz();
Baz = null;
(function(Bar) {
   Bar.fn.myPlugin = function() {
       return "test";
   };
})(Foo);
Foo.myPlugin(); //returns test
```

This works, and leaves Baz assignable.  Not sure if that is how jQuery does it or not.

Comment: jQuery puts has something liek Baz.fn = Baz.prototype; inside of the Baz class. Then, after it's instantiated you can do Baz.fn.whatever = function() etc...

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you never execute the line:

```
Foo.fn = Foo.prototype;
```

in your `Foo()` function.

**Functions only execute when you call them**.

Try using the singleton pattern:

```
var Foo = new function Foo() {
    this.fn = this.prototype;
};
```

In this case, you're creating an instance of the `Foo` object by calling the `new` operator on the named anonymous `Foo()` function.

Comment: What if the object takes constructor arguments like:
var Foo = new function Foo(a,b,c) {this.fn = this.prototype;this.doSomething = function() {alert(a);};};

Comment: How are the argument values attained?  Are they available on page load?

Comment: In the existing model, they are passed in on instantiation of the object. Like var Bar = new Foo(a,b,c);

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an issue for jQuery.  There's at least one problem in your code, as pointed out in another answer.

If you are serious about understanding this, John Resig (the original author of jQuery) has put together an excellent interactive tutorial called [Learning Advanced Javascript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/).